# Google Sheets: Trying to GetValue -> SetValue with Bitcoin Prices and print it anywhere in the sheets. 2 Codes

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal:
I'm trying to print (or stamp) the value of bitcoin each time there is word called "printprice" anywhere in the sheet.

My problem:
I have been very unsuccessful getting this as I have been trying to get the solution from two different codes

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function onEdit() {
  // simple timestamp -- when a single "T" is entered in a cell, replace it with a timestamp
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/rC6MpQDC7n4/discussion
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if (cell.getValue() == "Timestamp") {
    cell.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

^ this works and prints new Date each time there's word "timestamp" anywhere in the sheet.

What I have been trying to do is to combine the data above with the down below without any success.

```
/* USAGE:
 *  Sheet -> Tools -> Script Editor...
 *  Paste this script
 *  Update the map (below) to your preferences
 *  Create a button in your Sheet and Assign Script: `test`
 *  et voila profit
 */
function test() {
  // maps currencies.tokens to sheet ranges
  getPrices({
    'USD': {
      'ETH': 'G6',
      'DASH': 'H6',
      'LTC': 'I6',
      'GNT': 'J6',
      'REP': 'K6',
      'BAT': 'L6'
    }
  });
}

function getPrices(model) {
  for (var currency in model) {
    var tokens = Object.keys(model[currency]).toString();
    var url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=' + currency + '&tsyms=' + tokens;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    for (var token in model[currency]) {
      updatePrice(
        model[currency][token],
        json[token]
      );
    }
  }
}
function updatePrice(range, price) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(range).setValue(1/price);
}
```

Hopefully you can provide help as this is a learning process for me as well!

Kind Regards Johan